# Using Wordpress methods in echo - doesn't seem to work correctly?

Tags: php, wordpress

Not even sure if methods is the correct terminology...

Here is the original working code:

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/logo.png" alt="Polished Logo" id="logo"/></a>
<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/separator.png" width="2" height="59" alt="Line" class="logo_line"/>
<p id="logo_title"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></p>
```

I wanted it to only execute on the homepage, so I wrote this:

```
<? 
if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == '/' ){
echo '<a href="'.bloginfo('url').'">
<img src="'.bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/images/logo.png" alt="Polished Logo" id="logo"/></a>
<img src="'.bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/images/separator.png" width="2" height="59" alt="Line" class="logo_line"/>
<p id="logo_title">'.bloginfo('description').'</p>';
}
?>
```

But it outputs the `bloginfo()` and the other declarations completely outside the html tags I have created. For instance, with `bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')` it will display the directory outside the `IMG` tags I created.

Any ideas? Apparently my syntax isn't correct or something....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`bloginfo` function directly echoes the output. In this case you should use `get_bloginfo` to add the returned value to the string and echo the complete string. I believe this will work

```
<?php
if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == '/' ) {
  echo '<a href="'.get_bloginfo('url').'">
    <img src="'.get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/images/logo.png" alt="Polished Logo" id="logo"/></a>
    <img src="'.get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/images/separator.png" width="2" height="59" alt="Line" class="logo_line"/>
    <p id="logo_title">'.get_bloginfo('description').'</p>';
}
?>
```

Here is a better alternative:

```
<?php if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == '/' ) { ?>
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>">
  <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/images/logo.png" alt="Polished Logo" id="logo"/>
</a>
<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/images/separator.png" width="2" height="59" alt="Line" class="logo_line"/>
<p id="logo_title"><?php bloginfo('description') ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

I also suggest using the `is_home()` function provided by wordpress to check for the homepage instead of checking the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` value.

Comment: Thanks so much! Sometime you get stuck in a rut and need someone to show you the right way

Answer (score 0):

bloginfo() outputs data with echo and returns nothing, so instead of trying to concatenate everything, just output in sequence, e.g.

```
echo '<a href="';
bloginfo('url');
echo '"><img src="';
bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');
//etc...
```

Ugly I know, but see answer by Nithesh for a possible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the template path without auto echoing it by the bloginfo() function use:

```
get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory', 'display' )
```